# Python: conversion from requests library to urllib3

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, urllib3

I need to convert the following CURL command into an http request in Python:

```
curl -X POST https://some/url
-H 'api-key: {api_key}'
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
-H 'Accept: application/json'
-d '{ "data": { "dirname": "{dirname}", "basename": "{filename}", "contentType": "application/octet-stream" } }'
```

I initially successfully implemented the request using Python's requests library.

```
import requests

url = 'https://some/url'
api_key = ...
dirname = ...
filename = ...

headers = {
    'api-key': f'{api_key}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

payload = json.dumps({
    'data': {
        'dirname': f'{dirname}',
        'basename': f'{filename}',
        'contentType': 'application/octet-stream'
    }
})

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

The customer later asked not to use pip to install the requests library. For this I am trying to use the urllib3 library as follows:

```
import urllib3

url = 'https://some/url'
api_key = ...
dirname = ...
filename = ...

headers = {
    'api-key': f'{api_key}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

payload = json.dumps({
    'data': {
        'dirname': f'{dirname}',
        'basename': f'{filename}',
        'contentType': 'application/octet-stream'
    }
})

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('POST', url, headers=headers, body=payload)
```

The problem is that now the request returns me an error 400 and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `.encode('utf-8')` on `payload` before passing as a parameter.

Alternatively, try to pass payload as `fields` without manually converting it to JSON:

```py
payload = {
  'data': {
    'dirname': f'{dirname}',
    'basename': f'{filename}',
    'contentType': 'application/octet-stream'
  }
}
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('POST', url, headers=headers, fields=payload)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I have tried all your suggestions without success ("encode ('utf-8')" returns the same error 400 and using "fields" without "json.dumps" returns the error "a bytes-like object is required, not dict")

Comment: It returns you 400 response, but does it contain some message/payload in the response with the details?

Comment: response.msg is None and response.reason is "Bad Request"

Comment: how was this resolved?